# Загрузилась ли реклама в NativeExpressAdView?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

Существует ли способ (кроме `setAdListener()`) узнать, загрузилась ли реклама в `NativeExpressAdView`, чтобы скрывать ее при неудачной загрузке?

Я делаю список с рекламой. Из `Fragment` передаю в `Adapter` список (`List`), состоящий из `NativeExpressAdView`. В `Adapter` во `ViewHolder` хочу или скрыть, или показать `NativeExpressAdView`, в зависимости от того, загрузилась реклама в этот `NativeExpressAdView` или нет.

Comment: Ну можно ещё метод `.withAdListener()` использовать у `AdLoader.Builder`. Или вам, в принципе, `AdListener` чем-то не угодил?

Comment: Я делаю список с рекламой. Из Fragment передаю в Adapter список (List), состоящий из NativeExpressAdView. В Adapter в ViewHolder хочу или скрыть, или показать NativeExpressAdView, в зависимости от того, загрузилась реклама в этот NativeExpressAdView или нет.